# Sorting objects in arraylist depending on how they appear on a website?

Tags: java, android, html, sorting

I'm fetching data over a page using Jsoup and I want to stock text and images in the format they appear on the website. I'm able to get the text and images but how can I sort them in my ArrayList so they can match the webpage?

```java
private String downloadHtml(String urlPath) {
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urlPath).get();
        String title = doc.getElementsByClass("entry-title").get(0).text();

        Elements pContent = doc.select("div.entry-content > p");
        Elements imgUrls = doc.select("div.entry-content > p > img");

        for (Element textContent : pContent) {
            String text = textContent.text();
            listFocused.add(text);
        }

        for (Element imgUrl : imgUrls ) {
            String imgLink = imgUrl.absUrl(("src"));
            listFocused.add(imgLink);
        }

        for(String output : listFocused) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ArrayList: " + output + "\n");
        }
        return null;

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "downloadHTML: Invalid Url " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "downloadHTML: IO Exception reading data: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "downloadHTML: Security Exception. Need permission? " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: That's a loaded question and probably can't be accurately done in a repeatable way since the webpage layout (the view) is usually controlled by CSS and script in the background. I could have the first div element in the HTML show up at the bottom of the screen and the last element show up on the top of the screen.

Comment: The layout stays the same. I just need to find a way to sort everything since I can't select the text and the image links at the same tiem while adding to the array..

Comment: I see. You either need to work the JSOUP query syntax (check out pseudo selectors that compare index in the dom tree) or if there is a way to implement the visitor pattern and walk the tree, you can do it that way too. As far as I can tell, the only walking that JSOUP does is when it converts it's object model to a w3c dom document and it's a protected package so you can't use it in your code.

Comment: I will try that thanks for your reply !